# Missing product dimensions

Tags: magento2, product-attribute, dimensions

I recently upgraded to Magento 2.3.3 from 2.3.2. And I noticed that the product dimensions no longer appear in the product admin page.
Even though the default set attribute still has them set.
Does anyone know why is it happening?

PS: I also had installed a fresh Magento 2.3.3 installation to see if the problem had something to do with the update or third party extensions.

Thank you!

[image: Degfault set attribute]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hy guys, those attributes are from Temando shipping module. We've been using it on our previous versions of Magento 2. So the best way to overcome this is to create our own dimension attributes.

Thanks.